# Test what cd has done ksh

Tags: ksh, cd-command

I'm facing a small issue here. I'm doing :

```
cd $(find . -type d | grep "${4:0:4}.*${4:4:2}.*${4:6:2}")
```

$4 is a data entered from the user. However, if the user doesn't respect the format to enter, it will do : `cd` 
Then, my `$?` will be 0 and not 1, and it will `cd` to my home.
I'd like to introduce this in my error case to (by error case, I mean : `if $? = 1`).
How can I do that ?

Comment: just test the `pwd` result after the `cd` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in two steps:

```
newdir="$(find . -type d | grep "${4:0:4}.*${4:4:2}.*${4:6:2}")"
if [ -z "$newdir" ];then
    # error out here
else
    cd "$newdir"
fi
...
```